# call a plsql procedure from C# to generate a dataset

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, dataset

```
Resource totalData = new Resource (ModelConstants.VIEWS, "Total Data"

        DataSet dsParameters = DatabaseAccess.initParametersDataSet();
        DataTable params = dsParameters.Tables["Parameter"];

        DatabaseAccess.addParameter(ref params, "C_RECORDSET", ParameterDirection.Output, DatabaseAccess.TYPE_CURSOR);
        DatabaseAccess.addParameter(ref params, Name, ParameterDirection.Input, DatabaseAccess.TYPE_VARCHAR, 30, Name.ToString());
        DatabaseAccess.addParameter(ref params, Sql, ParameterDirection.Input, DatabaseAccess.TYPE_CLOB, 40, Sql.ToString());
        DatabaseAccess.addParameter(ref params, Path, ParameterDirection.Input, DatabaseAccess.TYPE_VARCHAR, 1000, Path.ToString());
        DatabaseAccess.addParameter(ref params, Empid, ParameterDirection.Input, DatabaseAccess.TYPE_VARCHAR, 20, Empid.ToString());
        DataSet ds = mdbQry.get_cursor("DB.JOB_REFRESH.ADD_MODIFIED", dsParameters);
```

The above code connects to Oracle DB. Executes the Database.PackageName.StoredProcedure i.e 'DB.JOB_REFRESH.ADD_MODIFIED' and returns rows to generate the dataset 'ds'.

Here is a part of the PLSQL procedure which has a cursor output parameter, this cursor returns all the rows which have to be stored in the dataset 'ds'.

```
PROCEDURE ADD_MODIFIED  
(
 I_NAME              IN  JOBS.NAME%TYPE,
 I_SQL               IN  JOBS.SQL%TYPE,
 I_PATH              IN  JOBS.PATH%TYPE,
 I_EMP_ID            IN  JOBS.EMP_ID%TYPE,
 C_RECORDSET         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
IS
 BEGIN
    OPEN C_RECORDSET FOR
      SELECT NAME, STATUS FROM JOBS ORDER BY MORDER;
  END;
END ADD_MODIFIED;
```

The procedure is getting compiled successfully and there is no problem in it.

I want the cursor C_RECORDSET to return the rows from the procedure. When this procedure is called from Visual Studio, it should return a valid dataset which displays on a datagrid.

When I try executing on Visual studio I get the below error when I insert a breakpoint at dataset 'ds':

```
Unable to retrieve data from the database. ORA-06550: line 1, column
15: PLS-00201: identifier 'DB.JOB_REFRESH' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

And when I execute the same procedure in PLSQL, I get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 396 in command -
EXECUTE JOB_REFRESH.ADD_MODIFIED('name','sql','path','empID')
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADD_MODIFIED'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I'm new to this, so please give inputs and guide me on how to rectify those errors and generate the correct dataset in 'ds'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294989/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-returns-ref-cursor

Comment: Are you trying to call `ADD_MODIFIED` or `ADD_MODIFIED_MV`? What is `EQDAS`? it looks like it get confused with `DB` in your system. You mght need to create a synonym for it.

Comment: Edited the post, please check.

Comment: Your PL/SQL call is failing because you're not providing the output parameter.  Rectify that first to ensure your procedure is working then look at the link @Rene posted to on the proper way to access Oracle db from .NET.