# How to append items of one list to another having same structure

Tags: c#, oracle

I have 2 list of same structure as follows:

```
List<OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA> items = new List<OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA>();

OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA { id = 1, parent = 0, text = "Initiate" };
items.Add(root);

root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA { id = 11, parent = 1, text = "Parts Selection" };
items.Add(root);

root = new OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA { id = 12, parent = 1, text = "Assumptions" };
items.Add(root);
```

Now I want to append the another list which is coming from Database and having the same structure

```
CREATE_ANALYSIS_SP_POPULATE_ANALYSISDATA fetchresult = this.domain.PopulateAnalysisData(input);

The fetchResult Contains OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA
```

These 2 list must be a final list and return should be `OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA` which contains all the Hardcoded and Database datas together..

class Structure is as follows:

```
public partial class OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA 
{       
    public System.Nullable<System.Decimal> parent { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<System.Decimal> id { get; set; }
    public System.String text { get; set; }
}

public partial class OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA
{       
    public System.Nullable<System.Decimal> parent { get; set; }
    public System.Nullable<System.Decimal> id { get; set; }
    public System.String text { get; set; }
}

public partial class CREATE_ANALYSIS_SP_POPULATE_ANALYSISDATA 
{      
   public List<OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA> OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA { get; set;}
   public List<OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA> OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA { get; set; }
}
```

I tried using following code but having some problem

```
items.AddRange(fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA);
```

Comment: What do you mean _but having some problem_ - please explain. And also  `fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA` - what type is that? By name it looks like a single object. By use of `Range` looks like a collection

Comment: Its saying AddRange having some invalid Arguments

Comment: Please show the `CREATE_ANALYSIS_SP_POPULATE_ANALYSISDATA` class

Comment: fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA : its a cursor returned from the Oracle

Comment: @Gilad Green..I have added the class

Comment: public CREATE_ANALYSIS_SP_SAVEORUPDATE_ANALYSISINFO SaveUpdateAnalysisInfo(Model.IN_CREATE_ANALYSIS input)
        {
            var spResult = this.ExecuteSP<Model.CREATE_ANALYSIS_SP_SAVEORUPDATE_ANALYSISINFO, Model.IN_CREATE_ANALYSIS>(input);
            return spResult;
        }

Comment: spResult has Set of Cursors that is returned from the SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SantyEssac : After looking at the code properly
I observed that you have by mistake given items.AddRange(fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA); instead of  items.AddRange(fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA);

The list type is OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA but you are adding OUT_POMONTOCARLODATA.

Please try the below one :
items.AddRange(fetchresult.OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to append a Oracle Cursor to a list of other types using `AddRange`. First read all the row returned from the cursor, convert them to your C# type and then add them to list.

Something along these lines:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(connectionObject);
cmd.CommandText = "Oracle_PkrName.Stored_Proc_Name";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
//Add parameters that are needed
//Then add the output cursor:
objCmd.Parameters.Add("YourCursorNameInProcedure", OracleType.Cursor).Direction 
    = ParameterDirection.Output;

connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(objCmd);
da.Fill(dataset);
```

At this point you have a `DataSet` so you can use `Enumerable.Select` to convert each item in it to `OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA`. After doing so you can do:

```
items.AddRange(dataset.Select(item => new OUT_POMONTOCARLOLOCALDATA { /*Set fields*/ } ));
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294989/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-returns-ref-cursor) for how to retrieve data from an Oracle Cursor

Comment: @SantyEssac - Was this helpful?